# With PostgreSQL getting ERROR: COPY format "CSV" not recognized

Tags: postgresql, errors, psql, copy

Whever I try to copy from

```
test=# \COPY table FROM 'file.csv' WITH ( FORMAT 'CSV', HEADER true );
ERROR:  COPY format "CSV" not recognized
```

What's the reason for this? I know I've used this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If format is a string, the string is case sensitive,

```
test=# \COPY table FROM 'file.csv' WITH ( FORMAT 'csv', HEADER true );
```

**But,** the format doesn't have to be a string,

```
test=# \COPY table FROM 'file.csv' WITH ( FORMAT CSV, HEADER true );
```

You're probably use to using the non-stringified version. The syntax for the `copy_options` is pretty hectic,

```
FORMAT format_name
OIDS [ boolean ]
FREEZE [ boolean ]
DELIMITER 'delimiter_character'
NULL 'null_string'
HEADER [ boolean ]
QUOTE 'quote_character'
ESCAPE 'escape_character'
FORCE_QUOTE { ( column_name [, ...] ) | * }
FORCE_NOT_NULL ( column_name [, ...] )
FORCE_NULL ( column_name [, ...] )
ENCODING 'encoding_name'
```

A lot of them only accept strings, but some of them accept regular tokens which get lowercased.

This *specific* thing isn't documented explicitly but you can find more information about [`COPY` here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)